# Merge two daily series into one hour series

Tags: python, pandas

I have two daily series and I have to merge them into one hour series with the 1st series for the first 12 hours and the 2nd series for the remaining hours.

Is there a more efficient way instead of building a list manually and convert it to series? Thanks

```
a = pd.Series(np.random.rand(5), pd.date_range('2015-01-01', periods=5))
b = pd.Series(np.random.rand(5), pd.date_range('2015-01-01', periods=5))
c = an hourly series
```

Comment: Perhaps if you showed an example with non-random data and the output you want it would be easier to divine your needs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

possibly:

```
>>> b.index += dt.timedelta(hours=12)
>>> pd.concat((a, b), axis=0).sort_index()
2015-01-01 00:00:00    0.150
2015-01-01 12:00:00    0.970
2015-01-02 00:00:00    0.746
2015-01-02 12:00:00    0.937
2015-01-03 00:00:00    0.523
2015-01-03 12:00:00    0.392
2015-01-04 00:00:00    0.606
2015-01-04 12:00:00    0.459
2015-01-05 00:00:00    0.221
2015-01-05 12:00:00    0.029
dtype: float64
```

and, `ts.asfreq('H', method='ffill')` to have hourly frequency.

Comment: thanks, but actually I mean - the resulting series should be a hourly series i.e. 24 data point per day and for the first 12 hours we use data from series a and the second half with the data from series b

Comment: @John you may do `ts.asfreq('H', method='ffill')` on the last value

Comment: look like the first line does not work? got the following error

TypeError: ufunc add cannot use operands with types dtype('<M8[ns]') and dtype('O')

Comment: @John what version of pandas are u using?

Comment: the version is pandas==0.14.1

Comment: @John well, that is one year old, maybe that is why